# AWS Organization accounts manangement

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-accounts

Let's assume in current AWS organization we have 2 developers accounts. From what I found it is a good practice to create a separate AWS account per environment and give access to these resources.

My question is:

What is the best way to share access to the resources (e.g. EC2, EKS, EFS) for multiple developers? Now I see only these two options:

- Create a separate AWS account for each developer and allow to access some resources by applying roles to that developers AWS accounts.
- Within a root account of each AWS environment create a IAM user account for each developer and from that point manage permissions by policies and user groups.

Please let me know. I appreciate any type of help! :)

Comment: " share access to the resources" - what kind of resources? I think the answer will depend what do you want to share. Access to S3 bucket? Databases?...

Comment: @Marcin I've just added some resource names I would like to share between accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup AWS SSO. Either integrated with your existing identity provider, or using the built in user system.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/what-is.html

This will allow you to create permission sets. Then, you can assign permission sets to users in particular accounts. This will create a role in the account which the users can assume

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution we chose.